# Using LIKE operator in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I have a SQL query like the following

```
select * 
from tbltask 
where taskstartdate = '2017-02-13 15:23:00.000'
```

This query is executing and I am getting proper data but, I want to use `like` command instead of `=`

So I changed my query to the following

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblTask 
WHERE TaskStartDate LIKE '%2017%'
```

with this I am getting the data of 2017.

And this is one of my row

```
038815c1-d8b3-43c8-bd28-1bc8cf7c0688    101 30b3af65-3222-42c4-8d6e-25ec275c5ba1    test    2017-02-13 15:23:00.000 2017-02-13 15:23:00.000 testing 2017-02-13 15:23:00.000 NULL        WIP 0   0   2   0   1   7788e4b1-e702-4c8a-9dfc-6ce7081f0a93    2017-02-13 15:47:14.747 0   NULL    30b3af65-3222-42c4-8d6e-25ec275c5ba1    1   NULL    0   30b3af65-3222-42c4-8d6e-25ec275c5ba1    0   Low ~/TaskFile/error-bg.jpg 0   NULL    0   0,0,0,0,0,0 0   NULL
```

but I want to fetch the data of a particular date, so I changed the query again to the following and fetching the data of the row which I showed above

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblTask 
WHERE TaskStartDate LIKE '%2017-02-13 15:23:00.000%'
```

but this is showing me blank data,

What is wrong in my like query?

Comment: Its not advisable to use `LIKE` operator when getting Specific Date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function to extract portions of dates. It should also make your queries more explicit about what you're seeking to achieve:

```
  select * 
  from tbltask 
  where 
      DATEPART(year,taskstartdate )=2017 and
      DATEPART(month,taskstartdate ) between 1 and 3
```

> (There are also specifically named functions, such as MONTH and YEAR, but I prefer DATEPART for consistency since it can access all components of a datetime)

You should try to avoid thinking of datetimes as having any kind of string format. Treating them as strings is one of the largest sources of errors we encounter.

Answer (score 0):

For using `Like` operator according to your scenario Use the next code:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM #tblTask 
WHERE convert(datetime2,TaskStartDate) LIKE '%2017-02-13 15:23:00.000%'
```

*Note*: using `Like` operator with Date is not best practice, use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use date casting. It will solve your problem.

```
CAST(TaskStartDate AS DATETIME) = CAST('2017-02-13 15:23:00.000'AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BETWEEN, to find out the data between that range

```
 SELECT * 
FROM tblTask 
WHERE TaskStartDate BETWEEN '2017-02-13 00:00:00.000' AND '2017-02-13 23:59:59.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying like operator on datetime column is not good. It will not use index. When you use like operator you need to query something like below.

```
select * 
from tbltask 
where CONVERT(CHAR(8), taskstartdate, 112) like '%20170213%'
```

Note: The above query will select all the rows whose date is 2017-02-13 irrespective of time.

For better performance use the below query

```
select * 
from tbltask 
where taskstartdate>= '2017-02-13' and taskstartdate<'2017-02-14'
```